# Encryption security

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

Let's say we have a number (12345) and we want to store it in the database but encrypted somehow.

We would like to avoid using any common encryption method.

We would like to know if doing this is secure, and if it is, HOW secure.

Original number: 12345

Shuffle: 35124

Add some data: 53412-35124-14352

then you store it on the db...

You can read the original number since you know where to look.
Is this method easlily reverse engineered?

Comment: This isn't encrypted, so yes.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using common encryption algorithms? They're common because they work well.

Comment: Ok you tell me this is easily broken, but how would you do it? thats my main point in this question. HOW would you break it?

Comment: Incredibly easy to break with just a little bit of known plaintext - probably just by inspection

Comment: Rule one of crypto is you do not invent your own algorithm. I suggest you read [this question and its answers](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say I have some way of sending you some numbers to store. I send you a few numbers, then I inspect your "encrypted" numbers.

```
Number I Sent       Number You Stored
12345               53412-35124-14352
11111               73671-11111-78162
67890               98126-80679-98983
```

Just by looking at that, you can quite easily see what's going on.

You really should not invent your own crypto algorithm. I'll just quote [Bruce Scheier](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram-9810.html#cipherdesign):

> Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break. It's not even hard. What is hard is creating an algorithm that no one else can break, even after years of analysis. And the only way to prove that is to subject the algorithm to years of analysis by the best cryptographers around.

Comment: Let's say you send me a GUID and I make store that with the same algorithm. Can you really tell the original number?

Comment: Well, the question isn't "can I?" - it's "could anyone?". But, yes, probably, if all you are doing is shuffling digits and bookending with random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The method is very **easily** reverse engineered and broken.

Something this simple would probably be broken with a human looking at it and noticing that the a constant mapping of positions. I give you abcd and you give me back bdca-bafd-jc6f. The extra data you added does not obscure the first 4 characters are linked

However if there was a more complicated method something similar to machine learning could be applied where computer will detect these direct patterns. Google translations use a version of this to produce translations through pure maths and books that have been translated into multiple languages.

In addition if you are only shuffling numbers the sample space of encrypting something will be quite small.

eg. If the encrypted text is: 1342

Better encryption would mean it could have originally been 0 - 9999 (10,000 total)

Your encryption tells me it started as one of these 24 charcters:

```
1234 | 2134 | 3124 | 4123

1243 | 2143 | 3142 | 4132

1324 | 2341 | 3214 | 4213

1342 | 2341 | 3241 | 4231

1423 | 2413 | 3412 | 4312

1432 | 2431 | 3421 | 4321
```

**Finally:**

Because the "secrecy" of your encryption comes from people not knowing how perform it you cannot ask the community to examine its strength without them knowing how you did it and thus cracking it.

All good encryption methods "secrecy" comes from a key or password which means you can share the method and ask the community to test its strength because you don't give them the key.